# Sketch the following Signal: $x(t)=3\sin(\frac{\pi t}{4})$

Tags: homework

I feel kind of overwhelmed by it, and would like someone to walk me through the steps of sketching the signal.

Comment: This is just asking how to plot a function. I'm really not sure whether this is on-topic here; do you know how to plot a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your physics knowledge you get that sine waves are usually equated, in the general case, as

$$y(t) = A * \sin(\omega t)$$

where $\omega = 2 \pi f$ and the periodicity is $T=1/f$

Comparing the general equation with your particular case, you have: $$2*\pi*f = \pi / 4$$
meaning that $$f=1/8 Hz$$
or $$T=1/f=8s$$
The amplitude is $A=3$

If you want to plot it in matlab, for example, just write

```
t = 0:0.01:16;
x = 3*sin(pi*t/4);
plot(x,t)
```

As a final comment, this is really a basic question and you should carefully read your textbook if you want to progress to more advanced topics.

Comment: The period of your signal $y(t)$ isn't $2\pi$, but it is $1/f$.

Comment: I've just updated the answer. Thank you for the heads-up Matt.